# Clean Architecture Use Case for determining Home Page sections -- UPDATED

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, clean-architecture

I'm experimenting with Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin's Clean Architecture, to use in an upcoming project.  This is a Spring MVC based web app.

One feature is that once a user logs in, their Home Page has various sections on it, based on their User Type.

In my little prototype, I've gotten things to work ok, but I'm not satisfied with my solution.  In particular, where should I determine what User Type I'm dealing with?

I'm trying to also follow Single Responsibility Principle, so I created an abstract ViewHomePageUseCase, which deals with the common sections on everyone's home page.  I also have ViewUserType1HomePageUseCase, etc., for the specific user types, which extend the base class.

Though currently, in my Spring @Controller, I have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage(Model model) {

    ViewHomePageResponseModel response;
    String userId = "test";

    int userType = this.getUserProfileUseCase.getUserType(userId);
    switch(s) {
    case 1:
        response = useCaseFactory.viewUserType1_HomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
        break;
    case 2:
        response = useCaseFactory.viewUserType2_HomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
        break;
    default:
        response = useCaseFactory.viewSimpleHomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
    }

    HomePageViewModel viewModel = presenter.presentHomePage(response);

    model.addAttribute("viewModel", viewModel);

    return "home";
}
```

though I don't like this Controller, since I have business logic in it.

In an earlier version of my prototype, I did try putting the "determine user type" function in the use case itself, then delegating to the correct use case.  Though it worked, I didn't like it either.

One thing I like in my current version is having several ViewHomePageUseCase classes, via inheritance, but I'm not clear on how or where to choose the use case based on user type.

I hope I'm being clear!

Any help is appreciated!

Chris

UPDATE --

What I ended up doing was to have separate Use Cases for each home page, and also a use case for deciding which home page is needed.  I also use factory for instantiating a use case.  Each home page use case just gets the data that particular home page needs.  The Spring Controller then is simplified:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private IUseCaseFactory useCaseFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(IUseCaseFactory useCaseFactory) {
        this.useCaseFactory = useCaseFactory;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage(Model model) {

    String userId = "steven"; // User Type 2
    // hardcoded userId's are used in the GetHomePageUseCase class.

    IHomePagePresenter presenter = this.useCaseFactory.getHomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
    HomePageViewModel viewModel = presenter.presentHomePage();

    model.addAttribute("viewModel", viewModel);
    return "home";
    }
}
```

My GetHomePageUseCase, which decides which home page is needed, is something like this:

```
public class GetHomePageUseCase implements IViewHomePageUseCase {

    private IUseCaseFactory useCaseFactory;

    public GetHomePageUseCase(IUseCaseFactory useCaseFactory) {
        this.useCaseFactory = useCaseFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public IHomePagePresenter getHomePage(String userId) {
        IHomePagePresenter presenter;

        //temporary
        //TODO - once users are in place, rewrite this function.
        String userRole;
        switch(userId) {
            case "chris":
                userRole = "UserType1";
                break;
            case "steven":
                userRole = "UserType2";
                break;
            default:
                userRole = "Public";
                break;
         }

         switch(userRole) {
         case "UserType1":
             presenter = useCaseFactory.viewUserType1HomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
                break;
         case "UserType2":
            presenter = useCaseFactory.viewUserType2HomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
            break;
        default:
            presenter = useCaseFactory.viewPublicHomePageUseCase().getHomePage(userId);
            break;          
        }

        return presenter;
    }

}
```

I'm still not certain about this approach.  While it's cleaner than the first version, I'm not quite satisfied with it.

A more general question: when you have a web page (in this case) that its features are dependent on some user role or permissions, how do I factor those user permissions into a Clean Architecture approach?  For instance, on another page (my View page), the basic data displayed is the same for all users, but based on the user role/permissions, the user might be able to Edit, Delete, etc., otherwise those buttons are not even displayed.  In this case (for my view page), I have boolean flags like showEditButton, which will be set via the Use Case, and the view page code itself just checks teh flag to show or hide the button.  Is that the correct way to do this in Clean Architecture?

Thanks again!!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Homepages are details, because the UI is a detail. Thus use cases should not deal with selecting home pages or sections.

> Chapter 22 - Use Cases
>
> We also do not expect this layer to be affected by changes to externalities such as the database, **the UI**, or any of the common frameworks. The use cases layer is isolated from such concerns.
>
> Martin, Robert C.. Clean Architecture: A Craftsman's Guide to Software Structure and Design (Robert C. Martin Series) Pearson Education.

Your use case `getUserProfileUseCase` is ok, but selecting the home page bases on the type is part of the ui controller.

> I'm trying to also follow Single Responsibility Principle, so I created an abstract ViewHomePageUseCase, which deals with the common sections on everyone's home page.

Even if the `ViewHomePageUseCase` follows the SRP (single responsibility principle) your controller doesn't. Every time a new user type is added you have to change the controller's switch statement. So what I would do is redirect to a controller that can handle the user type.

```
String redirect = MessageFormat.format("redirect:/home/{0}?userId={1}", userType, userId);
return new ModelAndView(redirect);
```

You can then add support for new user types by creating a new controller class, e.g.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("home")
public class UserType3HomePageController {

    @Autowired
    private UserType3InfoUseCase useCase;

    @GetMapping("/{userType}")
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(@PathVariable int userType, @RequestParam userId) {
        UserType3Info userInfo = useCase.getUserInfo(userId);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("userType3Home");
        modelAndView.addObject("userInfo ", userInfo);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Then you also have separation of concerns in the controllers. This also makes sense since the different home pages usually show different user data. Thus it makes sense to create a view for each type. Otherwise you might end up with switch statements (or if/else) in the view.

Comment: Sorry the late reply, I did see your answer earlier but been busy here at work on other aspects of this project.

Comment: The decision of which Home Page to display is a Use Case issue I believe.  However, it sounds like your saying to also have separate URLs and therefore Controllers for each user type Home Page, which is a possibility.  I was kind of hoping not to have to separate things out that much, but then again, it would follow SRP better.  The likelihood of needing to add new user types is remote in our case.  I'll update the original question above with what I ended up doing.